# textDecoration: line-through not working in React Native styled component

Tags: css, react-native, mobile, styles

I created a styled component

```
const StrikeThrough = styled(StandardText)`
    textDecoration: line-through;
`;
```

and called it with children, similar to `<StrikeThrough>Write text here</StrikeThrough>` but the text rendered doesn't have this decoration. Why might this be?

**EDIT:** Other things I've tried that don't work

```
const StrikeThrough = styled(StandardText)`
    textDecorationLine: line-through;
    textDecorationStyle: solid;
`;
```

```
const StrikeThrough = styled(StandardText)`
    text-decoration: line-through;
`;
```

**EDIT:**
To answer my own question, it looks like I had to do it on the Text component and couldn't make a styled component on top of my styled component.

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-decoration` instead of `textDecoration`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Styled Component so use `text-decoration` instead of `textDecoration` and use dot instead of brackets:

```
const StrikeThrough = styled.Text`
    text-decoration: line-through;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `text-decoration: line-through;`

you can also style the line with `text-decoration-color: red`